# My Trigger not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have trigger after insert in Table1 will insert in Table2 , after update columnA in Table1 will update in Table2 Status_Column where Table1.id=table2.id, after delete row in table1 will delete row in table2 where table1.id=table2.id.

```
 create TRIGGER mytrigger
       ON  Table1
       after UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE
    AS 
    Begin
        if  update (columnA)
            BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON; 
                declare @ID int
                select @ID = ID from DELETED    
                UPDATE Table2 
                SET T2.Status_Column ='Updated'
                From Table2 T2
                inner join Table1 T1 on T1.ID = T2.ID
                where T1.ID = @ID
            End
        else if exists (select * from inserted)
            Begin 
            declare @table2_ID int
            select @table2_ID = ID from inserted    
                insert into table2 (ID,Status_Column) values  (@table2_ID,'New')
            End
        else if exists (select ID from deleted)
            Begin
                delete from table2
                from table2 T2 , Deleted d
                where t2.id= d.id
            End
    End
```

Only the delete statement working :(

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations.  Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always contain exactly one row is generally a bad plan.  If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then please add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement.  (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: The UPDATE() function returns true for both INSERT and UPDATE operations, so your logic will need a little work.

Comment: @HABO what do you suggest for alter in this trigger ?

Comment: @HABO I'm not professional :) I still learning triggers :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fundamental flaw is that you seem to expect the trigger to be fired **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case in SQL Server. Instead, the trigger fires **once per statement**, and the pseudo table `Deleted` might contain **multiple rows**.

Given that that table might contain multiple rows - which one do you expect will be selected here??

```
select @ID = ID from DELETED
```

It's undefined - you might get the values from arbitrary rows in `Deleted`.

You need to rewrite your entire trigger with the knowledge the `Deleted` **WILL** contain multiple rows! You need to work with set-based operations - don't expect just a single row in `Deleted` !

Comment: I changed else if exists (select * from inserted) to if (select * from inserted) ,, and every thing work but if I update the trigger update and insert in the same time .. what would change also to work ?